# terraform aws iam_policy: Creating...failed with Policy document should not specify a principal

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform-provider-aws

What I am trying to archive is getting an IAM role with an attached policy in AWS. The terraform script for policy creation is:
iam_policy.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "js_csm_iam_policy" {
  name        = "js_csm_iam_policy_02-2021"
  path        = "/"
  description = "My CSM policy created 02 2021"
  policy = file("cmsiampolicy.json")
}
```

and another script to create the role as well as attach the plolicy created above with
iam_role.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "js_csm_iam_role" {
  name               = "js_csm_iam_role_02_2021"
  assume_role_policy = file("csmiamrole.json")
}

##
### IAM role poliy attachment
##
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "assign-policy1" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.js_csm_iam_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.js_csm_iam_policy.arn

}

##
###  instance_profile
##
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "js_csm_profile1" {
  name = "js_csm_instance_profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.js_csm_iam_role.name
}
```

csmiamrole.json

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
     "Principal": {
       "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
     },
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Sid": ""
   }
 ]
}

terraform apply  -auto-approve
aws_iam_role.js_csm_iam_role: Refreshing state... [id=js_csm_iam_role_02_2021]
aws_iam_instance_profile.js_csm_profile1: Refreshing state... [id=js_csm_instance_profile]
aws_iam_policy.js_csm_iam_policy: Creating...

Error: Error creating IAM policy js_csm_iam_policy_02-2021: MalformedPolicyDocument: Policy document should not specify a principal.
        status code: 400, request id: 53da615d-0541-4b94-ac28-f2e4fdfc23be
```

Comment: What is the content of cmsiampolicy.json?